# Excel isnumber if combination to check a text

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to check a cell to see if it contains double quotes or Ø symbol. if it contains I will take left part of the sign if it doesn't I will take all the text.
To manage this I wrote the following code:

```
=if(
ISNUMBER(
LEFT(B2;SEARCH("∅";B2;1)-1);
LEFT(B2;SEARCH("∅";B2;1)-1);
    if(
    ISNUMBER(
    LEFT(B2;SEARCH("Ø";B2;1)-1);
    LEFT(B2;SEARCH("Ø";B2;1)-1;
        IF(
        ISNUMBER(
        LEFT(B2;SEARCH(CHAR(34);B2;1)-1);
        LEFT(B2;SEARCH(CHAR(34);B2;1)-2);B2
        )
    )
)
```

but Excel gives me this error.

> "you have entered too many arguments for this function"

I couldn't figure out where is the error.

I am new to Excel formulas.

Comment: ISNUMBER only accepts 1 argument, you're trying to pass 3 to it ...

Answer (score 0):

Excel may want **,** not **;** in its formulas (*edit: this depends on region*) but the main issue is that `isnumber` only has one argument.

so like this

```
isnumber(your number)
```

and

```
 if(test,true condition,false)
```

**EDIT**
I think there is a bracket missing after your ISNUMBERs. There are there only to check your search returns a value.

Remove the ** they are only there to draw attention.

```
=if(
ISNUMBER(
LEFT(B2;SEARCH("∅";B2;1)-1)
         **)**;
LEFT(B2;SEARCH("∅";B2;1)-1);
    if(
    ISNUMBER(
    LEFT(B2;SEARCH("Ø";B2;1)-1)
             **)**;
    LEFT(B2;SEARCH("Ø";B2;1)-1;
        IF(
        ISNUMBER(
        LEFT(B2;SEARCH(CHAR(34);B2;1)-1)
                **)**;
        LEFT(B2;SEARCH(CHAR(34);B2;1)-2);B2
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: like Mlucas said in my region excel wants semicolon instead of comma

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("ø",B2)),ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(34),B2))),B2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("ø",B2)),LEFT(B2,FIND(CHAR(34),B2)-1), LEFT(B2, FIND("ø", B2)-1)))`

In your region you may need to use semicolons instead of commas:

`=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("ø";B2));ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(34);B2)));B2;IF(ISERROR(FIND("ø";B2));LEFT(B2;FIND(CHAR(34);B2)-1); LEFT(B2; FIND("ø";B2)-1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, managed to do it, after some of you reminding me isnumber takes only 1 argument

Here is the working formula if anyone is interested

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("∅";B2;1));LEFT(B2;SEARCH("∅";B2;1)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ø";B2;1));LEFT(B2;SEARCH("ø";B2;1)-1);IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHAR(34);B2;1));LEFT(B2;SEARCH(CHAR(34);B2;1)-1);B2)))
```

i used 2 different ∅ signs as it may change according to the source i took.